# How to read a server based file with React

Tags: reactjs, testing, build

I am able to read a config.json file (using fetch) which I included in my public directory with the "build" system, however when I test my system (`yarn start ->localhost:3000`) I get a 404. Browsing to `localhost:3000/config.json` directly in my browser serves me this file.

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I was using this code:

```
fetch(CONFIG, {
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
         }
}).then etc
```

This resulted in a 404 when using

```
yarn start -> localhost:3000
```

but was ok when using the build.
After changing "POST" to "GET" it also worked on localhost:3000